# In customized JFileChooser select one from the JComboBox perform that particular action

Tags: java, swing, action, customization, jfilechooser

i open file through Customized JFileChooser Then i add JComboBox. When i select one from the JComboBox that particular action performed for particular file. For example,my text file contains some text like "once we complete". When i select the binary form JComboBox. It display in textarea like " 63 6F FD 70 6C 65 74 once we complete".

Here is my code,

```
public class CustomJFileChooser {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                FileChooser frame = new FileChooser();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

 final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 JComponent panel = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT));
 JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
 comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "text", "binary" }));
 panel.add(new JLabel("FileFormat: "));
 panel.add(comboBox);
 chooser.setAccessory(panel);
 JComponent center = null;
 BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) chooser.getLayout();
 for (Component child : chooser.getComponents()) {
        if (BorderLayout.CENTER == layout.getConstraints(child)) {
            center = (JComponent) child;
        }
    }
 if (center != null)
        center.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Open File Chooser");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        }
    });
 frame.getContentPane().add(button);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);

}

 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: wat exactly you want to achieve you have an error FileChooser frame = new FileChooser(); it should be JFrame instead of FileChooser()

Comment: exactly i need the file should be opened in textarea binary format when the binary item selected from dropdown box. aboue example working properly.@mussdroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just calling `showOpenDialog` without obtaining a reference to the result, do this

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

Then you check if the `result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION` which means the <kbd>Open</kbd> button was pressed. Then you can get the selected file

```
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Then you want to check the selected item in the combo box. If it equals "binary", do your binary action, else do text action. Something like

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String type = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if ("binary".equals(type)) {
                // do binary action
            } else {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    textArea.read(reader, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See more at [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: You may want to update your post (with updated code) if you want further help. No really sure what you mean